# what's the different between gcloud components tools and the original tools?

Tags: gcloud, kubectl, minikube, google-cloud-sdk

As the [gcloud components](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components) doc said, we can install some tools like: `minikube`, `kubectl` using the below command:

```sh
gcloud components install minikube
```

What's the difference between the tools(`minikube`, `kubectl`) installed by `gcloud components install` command and the original tools [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube)?

Does gcloud sdk have any customization or restrictions on these tools?

Can I use the original [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) and `kubectl`(e.g. installed by `brew install kubectl` command) to replace the gcloud component tools?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only difference is the package manager and how you installed the component. Cloud SDK pulls the external components [based on the latest version of the SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#updating_components). As example, by updating to the latest SDK (as of now 315.0.0), you'll be able to install Minikube 1.14.0. Checking the version of this component will also display a commit version that you can check on the official repository.

If you need to work on a feature that is available on the latest version, then I suggest that you continue using Homebrew. However if not, and you want your components managed by Google, then installing it via Cloud SDK is also a good choice.